# Load pointer using ds (lds) instruction in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

There is a instruction in assembly level programming known as LDS(Load pointer using ds).

For example lds ax,23[si]

this instruction copies the first 16 bits of the word in the memory location ds:23[si] into the ds register and the remaining 16 bits into the ax register.

The working of this register is clear to me,but what is the practical use of this instruction?

Comment: Practical use is fast loading of both address components in one instruction.  BTW, correct location is: first 16 bits are for AX, next 16 bits for DS.

Comment: In 16-bit code you need long and short pointers.  This is a long one that allows addressing the full megabyte, short ones can't go beyond 64KB.  Sucked pretty heavy and everybody breathed a sigh of relief when it all got completely irrelevant 20 years ago.  Unfortunately not at SO.